# Converting a bytestring to a list of 7 bits bytes

Tags: haskell

I have to convert a ByteString into a list of 7 bits bytes. For example, bytes with a, b, c, d etc. bits:

```
abcdefgh ijklmnop qrstuvwx yz...
```

should be converted to:

```
abcdefg hijklmn opqrstu vwxyz...
```

I use the Binary-Bits package in order to do it. My `convert8to7` function is recursive but the Binary-Bits does not provide any mean to check for the lack of bits whereas the `Get` monad does have `isEmpty` or `remaining` functions.

Here’s my code:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Binary.Bits.Get
import Data.Binary.Get (runGet)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8

convert8to7 :: BitGet [Word8]
convert8to7 = do
    bits <- getWord8 7
    rest <- convert8to7
    return (bits : rest)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let datas = pack "Hello world!"

    print $ runGet (runBitGet convert8to7) datas
```

When I run this code, it logically says:

```
Data.Binary.Get.runGet at position 12: demandInput: not enough bytes
```

Can I do this conversion with Binary-Bits or should I look for an other package ?

*Update*

Here’s my code based on user5402 answer:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.Binary.Bits.Get
import Data.Binary.Get (runGet)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS

convert87 :: Int -> BitGet [Word8]
convert87 n
    | n == 0    = return []
    | n < 7     = do bits <- getWord8 n
                     return [shiftL bits (7 - n)]
    | otherwise = do bits <- getWord8 7
                     rest <- convert87 (n-7)
                     return $ bits : rest

to87 :: BS.ByteString -> [Word8]
to87 datas = runGet (runBitGet (convert87 len)) datas
           where len = fromIntegral $ BS.length datas * 8

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let datas = BS.pack "Hello world!"
    print $ to87 datas
```

Comment: The version of Binary-Bits on hackage is very out of date. The one on Github has had `isEmpty :: BitGet Bool` since April 1 2003.

Comment: Though it’s out of date, I will stick to the version provided by hackage. First it will be easier to maintain, second the `isEmpty` function does not allow me to handle the case where there are not enough bits to form a 7 bits byte. Thanks

Comment: Fair enough. There's nothing about the structure of `BitGet` that would prevent adding a function that does exactly what you want, but once again it wouldn't be in hackage. Seeing a package on hackage that out of date has left me wondering though: do they have a procedure for taking over abandoned projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to keep track of the number of bits to decode - the `BitGet` monad doesn't know when the end of input has been reached.

Try this:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Binary.Bits.Get
import Data.Binary.Get (runGet)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS

convert87 :: Int -> BitGet [Word8]
convert87 n
  | n < 7     = do bits <- getWord8 n
                   return [bits]
  | otherwise = do bits <- getWord8 7
                   rest <- convert87 (n-7)
                   return $ bits : rest

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let datas = pack "Hello world!"
        len = fromIntegral $ BS.length datas * 8
    print $ runGet (runBitGet (convert87 len)) datas
```

*Update*: Here is the way to detect end of input in the `Get` monad (on top of which the `BitGet` monad is implemented). It relies on the Alternative class for `Get`. The function `chunks7` breaks up a byte string into chunks of 7 with any remainder going into the last chunk.

As far as I can tell, `BitGet` does not implement the Alternative class - although I'm sure it could.

```
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Data.Binary.Get
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8
import qualified Data.ByteString as BSW
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BSL
import Control.Applicative -- used for (<|>)

chunks7 :: Get [[Word8]]
chunks7 = do
  b <- isEmpty
  if b
    then return []
    else do chunk <- fmap BSW.unpack (getByteString 7)
                     <|> fmap BSL.unpack getRemainingLazyByteString
            rest <- chunks7
            return $ chunk : rest

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let datas = pack "Hello world! This is a test"
    print $ runGet chunks7 datas
```

Comment: Thanks! It was actually simple but I couldn’t get it :-D